# Theme CSS overrides my CSS. How do I fix this?

Tags: theming, 8

Trying to customize this theme called Emon, but any theme styles I write bootstrap.css/template.css takes precedence even if we use identical selectors. I don't want to edit bootstrap.css/theme.css obviously, or use !important all over the place.

The theme offers a "Write your own CSS" section which has it at an inline-level, but it's not the easiest to maintain this way (though it's looking more attractive every minute).  I saw libraries-override/extend, but wasn't able to accomplish what I want like this.

Again, I'm looking to tell Drupal to honor my stylesheet over the others without removing them.  What is the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: Where you write the css? In module or in theme?

Comment: As you can [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/srccf6wt/4/) whatever is last is what gets applied. So it seems that styles.css is getting loaded before boostrap.css. Check your theme.info file to see if styles is before boostrap, if so all you have to do is switch places.

Comment: Originally it was in the bottom of the 'global-components:' CSS section  I tried moving it to the top, no change.  I moved the stylesheet into it's own library and called it after 'global-components' in theme.info.yml still no change.

Comment: @JonCarlyon did you flush the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Copy html.tpl file from your core module and place it in your themes folder ,look at the head element of your template then copy the path(link) of your CSS file and place it (at the last)after the 
themes CSS into the head tag.